# Access denied when trying to start solr

Tags: windows, solr, cmd

I have used lower version of Solr running on Tomcat without any problem , but when I try to start Solr 5.3.0 with cmd I get the error like this:

`bin>start solr
Access is denied.`

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
bin>.\solr start
```